# Обратиться к методам динамически созданного UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Возникла следующая ситуация... На форме есть TabControl и 2 кнопки.
Первая кнопка добавляет новые вкладки к TabControl и в "Content" этих вкладок помещается уже заранее готовый UserControl (он имеет свои объекты/свойства и методы).

Вторая кнопка, по идеи, должна обращаться к какому - нибудь из методу этого самого UserControl.

Собственно вопрос и заключается в следующем: как обратиться к объектам/свойствам/методам динамически созданных UserControl в раных вкладках. К примеру: создались 2 вкладки и по нажатию на вторую кнопку, обращение к UserControl происходит только к тому, вкладка которого сейчас в фокусе.

Нефига на словах не понятно, поэтому нарисую макет в пеинте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблем с созданием вкладок и помещения в них UserControl не возникает, делают вот так:

Код для кнопки добавляющая вкладку:

```
mainTab.Items.Insert(mainTab.Items.Count - 1, AddTabItem("test_" + mainTab.Items.Count));
```

---

```
private TabItem AddTabItem(string nametab)
{
    UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
    TabItem tab = new TabItem();
    tab.Header = nametab;
    tab.Content = uc;
    return tab;
}
```

Никаких "ItemSource", "Binding" не использую. В xml разметке самый обыкновенный TabControl который имеет только параметр "Name" и "Margin".

Comment: `Никаких "ItemSource", "Binding" не использую.` - а зря, ох как зря..

Comment: Возможно. 1-й раз делал именно через ItemSource, но в таком случаи, если в одной вкладке проводить какие - либо действия (текст там добавить или еще что), то это происходит во всех вкладках сразу.

Comment: У вас Control один или несколько в TabControl?

Comment: UserControl один, а вот в самом UserControl контролов много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть что-то такое,

```
TabItem tabItem = _tabControl.Items
                                   .OfType<TabItem>()
                                   .FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsFocused == true);
var uc = tabItem?.Content as UserControl1;
uc?.MyMethod();
```

условие на поиск нужного сами скорректируете...

Comment: Да, вроде то что нужно. Благодарю.

Comment: Да, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Я все же считаю, что UserControl - это View, который содержит часть представления, логика у него должна быть минимальная.

Давайте попробуем реализовать что то подобное. Я лично буду делать с возможностью расширения и по этому использую интерфейс. Его роль проста, содержать в себе заголовок вкладки:

```
public interface ITabViewModel
{
    string Header { get; set; }
}
```

Далее нам понадобится некая ViewModel, которая будет содержать в себе реализацию определенной вкладки. В моем примере она будет содержать заголовок, цвет, текст и метод обновления цвета:

```
public class ViewModelA: VM, ITabViewModel
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    private Brush _color;

    public Brush Color
    {
        get => _color;
        set
        {
            _color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateColor(Brush color) => Color = color;
}
```

Как видите мы унаследуем от VM (это базовый класс, который содержит в себе INotifyPropertyChanged), а также реализуем ранее созданный нами интерфейс.

Имея все это, мы можем все это объединить в, давайте создадим MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> TabItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>();
    public ITabViewModel SelectedTab { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        AddTestData(); //Грузим некие тестовые данные
        TestOtherMethod(); //Вызываем метод у выделенной вкладки
    }

    private void AddTestData()
    {
        //Некие данные
        TabItems.Add(new ViewModelA { Header = "Вкладка 1", Text = "Привет мир!", Color = Brushes.Aqua });
        TabItems.Add(new ViewModelA { Header = "Вкладка 2", Text = "Привет земля!", Color = Brushes.Azure });
        TabItems.Add(new ViewModelA { Header = "Вкладка 3", Text = "Привет космос!", Color = Brushes.Bisque });

        //Выделяем первую вкладку
        SelectedTab = TabItems.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private void TestOtherMethod()
    {
        var item = SelectedTab as ViewModelA;
        item?.UpdateColor(Brushes.Green);
    }
}
```

Привяжем все это дело:

```
private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = MainViewModel;
}
```

Теперь давайте разберемся с XAML. В нем нам надо создать TabControl, который будет привязан через ItemSource к нашей коллекции TabItems. Также в ресурсы зададим DataTemplate, что бы под определенную ViewModel нам выдавало нужный Control. Ну и также привяжем Header через ItemContainerStyle. В итоге выйдет что то вроде этого:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
            <local:UserControl1 Text="{Binding Text}" Color="{Binding Color}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Сам Control я показывать не буду, там заданы два DependencyProperty (Text и Color), сам дизайн состоит из Border, внутри которого TextBlock.

Ну что, запустим и посмотрим что вышло?

[image: Result]

Как видим у нас появилось 3 вкладки, первую мы изменили на зеленую через код.
С помощью такого подхода вы получите удобное управление всеми вкладками, а также возможность их расширения путем добавления другого Control'a и ViewModel.

Удачи в программирование!

Comment: Тоже как вариант, но ответ который дан выше оказался более подходящим.